# Android Studio "Unfortunately the Application had to stop" error.

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to pass some variables from one class to another in Android Studio, but my application keeps crashing and I don't know why.

This is the method of the class that executes onClick and calls the other:

```
 public void sendInfo (View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, InfoActivity.class);

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String name = editText.getText().toString();

    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    String surname = editText2.getText().toString();

    EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    String mail = editText3.getText().toString();

    EditText editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    String age = editText4.getText().toString();


    InfoActivity activity = new InfoActivity();

    activity.displayInfo(name,surname,mail,age);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And this is the method that is being called. It takes the parameters passed and adds them to a TextView:

```
public void displayInfo(String name, String surname, String mail, String age) {

    TextView textview =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    TextView textview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView textview3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextView textview4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    textview.setText(name.toString());
    textview2.setText(surname.toString());
    textview3.setText(mail.toString());
    textview4.setText(age.toString());


}
```

Any ideas why the app is crashing? What is wrong?

Comment: `InfoActivity activity = new InfoActivity();` never create an instance of an `Activity` except via an `Intent`.  You cannot treat activities like POJOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a method of another `Activity` before it is created through `startActivity(intent)`.

Furthermore in order to pass values to another Activity you have to use the method `Intent putExtra(...)`. (See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) what can be passed)

#### Example

In your first activity do something like this:

```
intent.putExtra("KEY_NAME", name);
// TODO other values that need to be passed
```

In order to retrieve this value in your second activity you have to do something like this (for example in your `displayInfo()` method):

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
textview.setText(bundle.getString("KEY_NAME"));
// TODO get the other values and set the text
```

Comment: You _could_ call a method in another activity, but whn this method uses `findViewById` for example, which needs the layout to be inflated first, the app will crash.

Comment: That's basically what I tried to say with *"before startActivity is called"*. But either way it's definitely something you shouldn't do ever.